# SVG path animation to begin on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I have an SVG path animation that at the moment is on an infinite loop. I'd like the animation to be invisible until it is triggered by a click event then once the animation is complete (one time, not infinite) the button should no longer work.

I've added a test button but the animation still seems to play as soon as the page is loaded and the button has no effect on it.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.dashed').toggleClass('path');
});
```

```css
.dashed{
  stroke-dasharray: 10;

}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M23.742,10.709
 c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
 c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
 c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
 c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>

<path class="dashed" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M23.742,10.709
 c-2.305,23.611-8.81,46.563-9.021,70.829c-0.252,28.966,22.237,43.666,47.06,55.482c23.642,11.255,42.368,15.766,68.461,16.631
 c19.993,0.663,40.08,2.97,59.853-1.723c23.301-5.531,45.542-17.598,66.978-27.933c19.248-9.281,38.831-21.86,41.946-45.201
 c5.539-41.51-54.993-47.073-81.885-42.17C159.05,47.212,89.37,104.633,77.387,164.629c-5.896,29.522-4.312,60.884,12.703,86.354
 c19.17,28.697,49.512,49.927,78.596,67.591"/>
</svg>


<input type="button" id="button" value="Animate" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) empty the class `.path` but keep it there:

```
.path { }
```

b) add the animation properties you removed from the `.path` into a new css class with replacing 'infinite' from the animation property to '1'.

```
.path-animation {
     stroke-dasharray: 1000;
     stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
     animation: dash 5s linear 1;
}
```

c) Use the following jquery to achieve the results you require:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   $('.path').attr('class', 'path path-animation');
   //5 secs delay to complete the animation before removing it and disabling the button.
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('.path').attr('class', 'path');
      $("#button").attr("disabled","disabled");
   }, 5000);
});
```

Sample Code: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/yVNxQG

Comment: Have your added jquery.min.js and also i dont see the js code on your page.

Comment: forgot to add $( document ).ready(function() {. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these small changes to your code:

1) Firstly remove the already existing `<path class="path"` from your first `<path>` element. You want the button to add this later onclick

2) Change your **animation iteration count** from your `animation: dash 5s linear infinite;` - The 'infinite' here says iterate the animation infinite times. Change that to `animation: dash 5s linear 1;`

```
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear 1;
}
```

3) Then to disable the button after first click, you could

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('.dashed').addClass('path');
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Simple .. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/krishna9960/atg5m6ym/7723/

Check this .. It should help...

For disabling button u can use this code

```
$("#button").click(function() {
          $('.path').css("animation"," dash 5s linear");
          $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
         });
```