# Start a svg animation onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

This following code works fine when an initial begin time is provided for the animation of the SVG polygon. But I can't figure out how to trigger it via javascript/jquery without providing a begin time to "vbanim" animation.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#v-b').beginElement();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to draw</button>
<svg width="100px" height="100px" preserveAspectRatio="false" viewBox="0 0 500 800">
  <polygon points="20,20 490,20 490,780 20,780" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="2" id="v-b" stroke-dasharray="3000"/>
  <animate xlink:href="#v-b" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="3000" to="0" dur="2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="vbanim"/>
  <animate xlink:href="#v-b" attributeName="fill" from="transparent" to="rgba(130,130,130,0.6)" dur="1s" begin="vbanim.end" fill="freeze"/>
</svg>
```

I need the stroke-dashoffset and the fill animation to occur only after the button has been clicked and prior that, the SVG shouldn't be visible at all. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check the console. 1. $('v-b') is not correct selector 2. $('#v-b').beginElement(); does not work either

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488526/svg-path-animation-to-begin-on-click-of-a-button

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad but I referred another answer which doesnt seem to work and its a polygon not a path animation so I dont think that works the same.

Comment: I just need a workaround to implement what I have mentioned in the question, to start both the animation when the button is clicked and before that the polygon shouldn't be displayed. If you change the begin to 0s in the first animate tag, you'll see what is the output required.

Comment: don't add the solution inside the quesiton ... you accepted an answer so either edit this answer or add your own anwser and accept it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The preferred working solution using beginElement() to indefinitely start the animation when an event is generated.

**Note-** *beginElement()* function works only with native javascript/ not Jquery.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  document.getElementById('vbanim').beginElement();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to draw</button>
<svg width="100px" height="100px" preserveAspectRatio="false" viewBox="0 0 500 800">
  <polygon points="20,20 490,20 490,780 20,780" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="0" id="v-b" stroke-dasharray="3000" />
  <animate class="anim1" xlink:href="#v-b" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="3000" to="0" dur="2s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" id="vbanim"/>
  <animate class="anim2" xlink:href="#v-b" attributeName="fill" begin="vbanim.end" from="transparent" to="rgba(130,130,130,0.6)" dur="1s"  fill="freeze"/>
  <animate class="anim3" xlink:href="#v-b" attributeName="stroke-width" from="0" to="10" dur="0.2s" begin="vbanim.begin" fill="freeze" id=""/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I am not sure what you want to achieve ..

Please see the link for the sample code..

https://codepen.io/deibu21/pen/jYQLEO

What I did is that I created a class in the animate tag..
then use the attr() of jquery to target the attribute of "begin"
Please see the code below..

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('svg animate.anim1').attr("begin", 2);
  $('svg animate.anim2').attr("begin", 3);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is close to what I need with the additional requirement that the SVG polygon shouldnt be visible at all before the button is clicked to draw it.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Adding another animate with it helped. Anways, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: animation using this is not smooth if the time limit specified is passed